# Plural for numbers as decades in French? (E.g. The '80s)

Tags: pluriel, nombres

Does French have an equivalent as referring to a certain decade as the plural of the tens place number the same way we could refer to decades as the plural for the tens place figure as in '80s or the '90s etc? If I say *Les soixante-dixes* or similar would that make sense?

Comment: *Dixes* wouldn't work anyway. Words ending with an *S* or an *X* are invariable so they are never pluralized in *‑SES* or *-XES*. *Le dix → les dix*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Les années soixante-dix* is a usual figure of speech. I think *années* plays here the same role as *-s* in English, since simply *les soixante-dix* doesn't seem to make much sense (unless it appears in a context, from which it is clear what one is referring to - see examples in the comments.)

Comment: Cf « les trente glorieuses ».  Ofc the period doesn't start in 1930.  I don't know if there are other examples of spans of years being referred to like this, or if it entered the language by itself. (Années is clearly implied by the gender). I'm also obviously not french.

Comment: On its own, would _les [numéro]_ not work the same as English ‘the [number]’ (without the plural), requiring some sort of head noun being understood from context? For example, in a novel you might imagine a criminal syndicate with 14 members being known as _The Fourteen_ in English; would it be natural for them to be known as _Les Quatorze_ in French as well?

Comment: @2e0byo « les trente glorieuses » designates the thirty year period between 1945 and 1975, and has nothing to do with  « les années trente », which designates the thirties :)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet If it is clear from the context what one is referring to, the number alone would make sense - e.g., [300](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/300_(film))

Comment: @Jenny exactly!  it was the only example of an implied années I could think of.  At least I'm assuming that glorieuses is agreeing with a supplied années.

Comment: There's a group of early twentieth-century composers known as "Les Six": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Six

Comment: @MichaelLugo since the discussion has clearly moved away from *decades* (to which the OP and my answer are referring to) I have expanded the last sentence, regarding the use of *article + number*.